# What is the composition of the oil-like fluid that seeps out of dry-cells over time?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

An experience a lot of us might've had; a dry cell (not completely depleted) when left in an electrical device for long periods of time, has this viscous fluid coming out that usually corrodes the terminals of the battery.

I almost always find this fluid, present as a sorta thin film over the terminals and the casing of the battery.

I'm told that the Ammonium Chloride in the cell, being slightly acidic reacts with the zinc casing of the cell, which is why dry cells don't last long (My teacher mentioned this during our Electrochem. class, he didn't mention anything about that fluid I was talking about though). Could this fluid possibly the result of that reaction? What are its chemical constituents?

Comment: Exactly which type of dry cell do you want to know about?All of them have different electrolytes.For example in alkaline cells it is potassium carbonate.

Comment: @ZOZ the Le Clanché kind......

Comment: ......now I'm not sure if it's Leclanché or Le Clanché.....

Comment: I doubt that's what you want.Because those cells used to be used in the 1800s.I wrote an answer regarding more recent cells. Lechlance is quite similar.

Comment: Not really :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leclanch%C3%A9_cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various kinds of dry cells.I will give some examples as to what is that oil-like fluid:

In **zinc-carbon** cell:

> Zinc carbon cells have a short shelf life as the zinc is attacked by
>   ammonium chloride. The zinc container becomes thinner as the cell is
>   used, because zinc metal is oxidized to zinc ions. When the zinc case
>   thins enough, zinc chloride begins to leak out of the battery. The old
>   dry cell is not leak proof and becomes very sticky as the paste leaks
>   through the holes in the zinc case. The zinc casing in the dry cell
>   gets thinner even when the cell is not being used, because the
>   ammonium chloride inside the battery reacts with the zinc. An
>   "inside-out" form with a carbon cup and zinc vanes on the interior,
>   while more leak resistant, has not been made since the 1960s.

In **alkaline** cells:

> Technically, that white fluffy corrosion that develops at the ends of
>   the battery (most often the negative end) is called potassium
>   carbonate.
>
> All batteries will slowly gradually self-discharge over time. This
>   will occur whether they are setting on the shelf (a much slower
>   process) or installed in a device (which often occurs much quicker) –
>   and dead batteries will eventually leak.
>
> Very high temperatures can also cause batteries to rupture and leak
>   (e.g. in hot car during the summer).
>
> The “alkaline” of the battery is potassium hydroxide (it’s the alkali
>   equivalent of acid’s hydrochloric acid), and this will leak out,
>   forming a white “fluff” of potassium carbonate, typically on the
>   negative end of the battery cell – because apparently the positive end
>   is vented better.

So the reason for the cell-corrosion varies with the type of the cell.

Read the Wikipedia page to know about the composition of electrolytes of different dry cells.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_cell

Comment: Would you also happen to know the product of the reaction between the ammonium chloride and the Zinc canister? I vaguely recall some source telling me it includes the complex  [Zn(NH3)4]2+, but I can't find sources backing that up....great answer by the way....

Comment: Yes you are correct.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_ammine_complex that's the most probable product as far as I know!